# nested loops for searching treemaps in Java

Tags: java, loops, treemap

In one part of my program I use the function below to make a very simple calculation. But except the first output from the first run of loop all are wrong. The map `getFuncTypeOrg` has 24 TreeMaps like this one with different sizes.

```
AUF_1427=[AUF_1427034486856_435, Function 20, 1.0, NotSet, ORA_1427034499672_440, Organizational unit 7, Computer-based appl. component 3, RechAnwendungsbaustein, hasType, Green]
```

The function suppose to give for this data the value Organizational unit 7=[100,1,1]. Its size is bigger than 6, its fifth value is equal to `org` value in another map and it contains `Green`. But it gives me `Organizational unit 7=[72.22222222222223, 18.0, 13.0]`
I can not figure out what is going wrong??

```
public TreeMap<String, List<Double>> orgFuncFuncType() {
    double typeNum = 0;
    double greenNumber = 0;
    double saturationOrg = 0;
    for (String org : getSortedAssignedOrg().values()) {
        List<Double> value = new ArrayList<Double>();
        for (List<String> entry : getFuncTypeOrg().values()) {
            if (entry.size() > 6 && entry.get(5).equals(org)) {
                typeNum++;
                if (entry.contains("Green")) {
                    greenNumber++;

                }

            }

        }

        saturationOrg = (greenNumber * 100) / typeNum;
        value.add(saturationOrg);
        value.add(typeNum);
        value.add(greenNumber);
        orgFuncFunctype.put(org, value);
        System.out.println(orgFuncFunctype);
    }
    return orgFuncFunctype;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had to set the counters to 0 at the end of main loop

```
        .
        .
orgFuncFunctype.put(org, value);
    greenNumber =0;
        totalNum = 0;
}
return orgFuncFunctype;
```